# Problem with nvidia driver - display not working properly after install

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I'm trying to do a fresh install of the latest lts ubuntu (14.04) on an old Dell Inspiron 6400 with a nvidia geforce 7300 video card.

Everything is going good with the installation, except that ubuntu is using by default the nouveau display driver (xserver-xorg-video-nouveau). The problem with this driver is that every graphic animation is really slow, just moving a window around is a pain.

So, I installed the correct driver from nvidia (for this card, I believe the correct version is nvidia-304). When I'm starting ubuntu, I access the log in screen without problem. But after that, the desktop won't load correctly. The background image is good, but everything else look terrible and won't work correctly.

[This image is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8bVg.jpg)

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: How did you install the "correct driver" for nvidia-304? Did you go to "Software & Updates" from dash and then found it in the "Additional Drivers" section?

Comment: Yes, it was in the additional driver section. The first time, I tried to install it from there. After that, I removed it and tried to install it from a terminal interface. (sudo apt-get install nvidia-304). Every time, I got the same problem.

Comment: When I check the driver compatibility on the nvidia website, it's also this version (304) that they recommend for this card (geforce 7300)

Comment: Try this: `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`. For [reference](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2124444).

Comment: Well, it's not working. When I use the nvidia current, it's installing the same version of the driver as previously. (304)

Comment: First, go to your dash and search for a utility named *Nvidia X Server settings*, and see if changing any settings might help you ([read this reference too](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958740)). If it doesn't work, raise a question on [superuser.com](https://www.superuser.com), it is appropriate for such hardware related issues. I personally don't have any expertise with nvidia drivers, otherwise my comment would have been an answer!

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem with nvidia 7300 go in laptop Acer Aspire 5635WLMi. The driver indicate from Nvidia as the correct one is the v. 304. This driver works rigth in Ubuntu 12.04 but does not work in Ubuntu 14.04. 
This is a big problem for users of nvidia 7300 go in laptops.

Comment: -1 because this doesn't answer the question. If you face similar problem, consider to *upvote* the question instead. This will make the question to be noticeable and more chances for it to get answered by someone.